# Pagination is limiting my csv export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-5, export-to-csv

I have added csv export and pagination feature in my app.

parent.rb

```
    CSV_HEADER = %w[parent_1_firstname parent_1_lastname address]
    def self.to_csv
        CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << CSV_HEADER
        all.each do |parent|
      csv << [
        parent.parent_1_firstname, 
        parent.parent_1_lastname, 
        parent.address

      ]
    end
   end
  end
```

controller.rb

```
def main_admin
        require 'csv'

        add_breadcrumb "Admin"
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
      Parent,
      params[:filterrific],
      select_options: {
        with_status: Parent.options_for_status
            }
    )   or return   
    @parents = @filterrific.find.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.csv { send_data @parents.to_csv }
    end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
        puts "Had to reset filterrific params: #{ e.message }"
        redirect_to(reset_filterrific_url(format: :html)) and return
    end
```

The issue I am facing is when I click on Download CSV on my main_admin.html.erb page. The CSV that is downloaded is just the first 10 parents but there are more than that. Like somewhere around 300 parents. I am not able to figure out the issue. Kindly help.

Update

```
if params[:format] == 'csv' then @filterrific.find.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.csv { send_data @parents.to_csv }
    else 
    @parents = @filterrific.find.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
```

Comment: Did you try removing pagination?

Comment: @iGian no. I ll try doing that.

Comment: @iGian yes it works fine if I remove pagination. But I need pagination

Comment: @iGian Any idea how it can be fixed?

Comment: Try with if `params[:format] == 'csv' then @parents=.... respond_with :csv else @parents = ....` etc..

Comment: @iGian  This is what I tried but I get error syntax error, unexpected => ...ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to only use pagination if format is not csv

```
@parents = @filterrific.find
@parents = @parents.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10) unless request.format == 'csv' #does pagination if not csv format

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
  format.csv { send_data @parents.to_csv }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made a single controller action respond to csv, html, or js, which is fine, but you only ever deal with a single object that represents all of your Parents - @parents. Your @parents instance variable is always paginated in all three of your action's responders. To fix this, you will need to use a second representation of Parents which is *all* of your Parents for your CSV export:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.js
  format.csv { send_data Parent.all.to_csv }
end
```

Don't forget to add the Filterific logic back in if you need it.

It should be noted that in this example, for a CSV export, you'd be creating the @parents object even though you would not use it, so you should move that in to the html and js responders to stop an extra unnecessary query.

Comment: I want to export the parents by adding the filterrific. it is not that I want to export all my parents.

Comment: *nod* so likely you would change Parent.all.to_csv to something like @filterrific.find.to_csv (removing the paginate component) or @filterific.find.map(&:to_csv) or @filterific.all.map(&:to_csv). I am not familiar with that gem, so I don't know the exact syntax.

Comment: I can't remove pagination. I need it.

Comment: Your pagination will still exist for your HTML and JS responders. It will not exist for your CSV responder, which is the issue you brought up - your CSVs are being paginated and you are only getting the first 10 Parents in the file.

Comment: I tried all the ways u suggested there is an undefined method error in each case

Comment: Did you try Parent.all.to_csv  ? That should have worked for you, albeit without filtering.

Comment: Yes I tried Parent.all.to_csv it works but I don't want that. I want csv export to work with filterrific.